# Деление массива(как дерево)

Tags: python

Нужно разбить массив в виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Массив м.б любого размера(длина массива -четное число)

```
import numpy as np
Y=list()
for i in range(1,9):
    Y.append(i)
MASS=list()
j=0
while len(Y)!=2:
    j+=2
    delit=int(len(Y)/2)
    MASS.append(np.array_split(Y,j))
    Y=np.array_split(Y,delit)
```

Понятно, что это бред...
Может есть идеи?

***Решение***:

```
j=0
i=0
while i!=len(Y):
    i+=1
    j = int(len(Y)/(2**i))
    print(j)
    try:
        MASS.append(np.array_split(Y,j))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: надо разбить по полам?

Comment: в итоге должно получится 4 массив: `[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]` правильно?

Comment: Как на картинке.

Comment: Верно. Но , есть массив , например, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]. Он сначала делится на 2 массива [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] и [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]. Потом эти два массива опять делятся на [1,2,3,4]  , [5,6,7,8] и [9,10,11,12] , [13,14,15,16]. Потом опять,каждый массив делится на 2

Comment: просто брать по два с шагом... два?

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял то так:

```
arr = list(range(1, 9))

res = [arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)]
```

Comment: Да, похоже промежуточные слои дерева никому не нужны )

Answer (score 1):

## Очень похоже на дерево отрезков

- Чётной длины недостаточно, нужна степень двойки.
- Нулевой индекс выкидываем и используем [1..2<sup>k+1</sup>-1].
- Для вершины `i` потомками являются `i*2` и `i*2+1`.
- Вершины с номерами [2<sup>k</sup>..2<sup>k+1</sup>-1] хранят данные.
- Вершины с номерами [1..2<sup>k</sup>-1] хранят агрегированные значения.
- Каждая вершина покрывает весь треугольник под собой.

```
┌───────────── 01 ─────────────┐
┌───── 02 ─────┐┌───── 03 ─────┐
┌─ 04 ─┐┌─ 05 ─┐┌─ 06 ─┐┌─ 07 ─┐
 08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15
```